# Font size and icons are very small in Yocto Image

Tags: linux, fonts, embedded-linux, yocto

I have generated a core-image-minimal Yocto Image for my Intel Custom Board. The font size is very small. Even I tried with Sato Image, the icon size is very small

How to increase the font size, which recipes I have to touch/modify in order to achieve my requirement..

Thanks for your time

Comment: What is the desktop manager & the windowing system? Ain't just a problem of screen resolution?

Comment: How to find that out, in a core-image-minimal system.. How can we modify the resolution

Comment: Maybe send a picture of your screen to see the problem (I always used headless systems)